# Smoke simulation - how to make a slow fog

Tags: smoke-simulation

I'm trying to achive a fog effect with smoke simulation. But what I'm getting looks more like a flame and is moving too fast.
Does anyone know how to make it very slow and smooth - as a real fog would behave ?

Here is my example and my smoke settings: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxWsWeQP5ugaeHQwQ3owa0t2cEk/view?usp=sharing

[image: smoke settings]

Comment: 'Velocity' value, when set high, then there is more turbulence. If you set the 'density' value and 'temperature' value both low then the smoke will go up slowly. See this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYNr0ZtyD1c

Comment: But if you make those values low the smoke doesn't rise and is flat on ground. I want it to be cloudy but move slow.

Comment: Then you should increasing the temperature value, to what you like ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways and you may need to use a combination of both depending on how slow you want to slow it down:

1) Change the Time: Scale with the CUBE DOMAIN
[image: domain]

2)
Slow down the frame rate. E.G. change 29.97 to 120 fps.  Unfortunately it's not a perfect solution- it will change the characteristics of your smoke and you'll basically have to tweak everything from the very beginning.