# Is it possible to create a fog / smoke aura in Blender?

Tags: shaders, toon-shading

I don't know how to name this effect, but I want to recreate this sort of fog that circles the character. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: is this character 2d or 3d? 3d: you could try [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33407/smoke-simulation-how-to-make-a-slow-fog) and render or apply at the appropriate frame?  I can't think of a shaders approach.

Comment: Is a 3D character. Thank you! I'm going to take a look